# Simple way to calculate values in a bitmask?

Tags: php, bitmask

Apologies - I'm not even sure I'm using the right terminology here.

I have a series of confidential documents and I'm creating a bitmask (?) to represent which of those documents a given user can view. (1 represents Doc1, 2 represents Doc2, 4 represents Doc3, 8 represents Doc4, 16 represents Doc5, etc.)

So, if a user can view docs 1, 2, and 5, the bitmask will be 19.

Where I'm *really* stumped, though, is how to reverse calculate the individual values "stored" in the bitmask. Currently, I'm using

```
if($docs2view==1) {
    $nextdoc = 1;
}
if($docs2view==2) {
    $nextdoc = 2;
}
. . .
if($docs2view==127) {
    $nextdoc = 1;
}
```

which is REALLY tedious and obviously very inefficient. Can someone point me toward the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a bitwise-and:

```
if( $docs2view & 1 ) {...}
if( $docs2view & 2 ) {...}
if( $docs2view & 4 ) {...}
if( $docs2view & 8 ) {...}
if( $docs2view & 16 ) {...}
```

Here, I'm testing individual bits.  If the bit is set, the condition will be non-zero (hence will evaluate to 'true').

You could possibly avoid a lot of code repetition by putting this in a loop and using the bit-shift operators (`>>` and `<<`).

---

You said:

> Thank you, paddy! But I only need the lowest value that evaluates
>   true. How do I tell the loop to stop as soon as it finds that?

You can either convert those statements to `elseif` so that only the first becomes true, or you can do this (assuming you only check the first 8 bits):

```
$nextdoc = 0;

for( $i = 0; $i < 8; $i++ ) {
    if( $docs2view & (1<<$i) ) {
        $nextdoc = $i + 1;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, paddy! But I only need the lowest value that evaluates true. How do I tell the loop to stop as soon as it finds that?